# SQL get MAX() value of values in a list

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

i have a database of transactions between customers that can be described as in:

```
Transaction ID  Sender  Receiver    Sender  Receiver Receipt
1   A   B   2   4
2   C   A   5   1
3   B   C   5   1
4   C   B   3   4
```

database is sorted ascending by transaction id; how is it possible to get the last receipt number (sender or receiver) for each customer

for example
A:1  (the last occurrence of A is in row 2 as a sender)
B:4  (the last occurrence of B is in row 4 as a Receiver)
C:3  (the last occurrence of C is in row 4 as a sender)

Thank You,

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the column names, because they're not clear in your question.
First create a query composed of 3 columns TransactionID, name, receipt. This returns double the rows from the original table: 1 row for the sender and the receipt and 1 row for the receiver and the receipt.  
From this result get only the rows that have max id for each name(snder or receiver):

```
WITH t AS(
  SELECT TransactionID, Sender AS name, SenderReceipt AS receipt FROM transactions
  UNION
  SELECT TransactionID, Receiver AS name, ReceiverReceipt AS receipt FROM transactions
) 
SELECT 
  name, 
  receipt 
FROM t
WHERE 
  t.TransactionID = (
    SELECT MAX(TransactionID) 
    FROM t AS tt
    WHERE tt.name = t.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the last transaction a user was involved in as sender and the same for receivers. Union both results and draw the last transaction a user was involved in in any role. Join the transaction and use a `CASE` to output the receipt depending on the role the user had in the transaction.

```
SELECT `Last Transaction`.`Sender or Receiver`,
       CASE `Last Transaction`.`Sender or Receiver`
         WHEN `elbat`.`Sender` THEN
           `elbat`.`Sender Receipt`
         WHEN `elbat`.`Receiver` THEN
           `elbat`.`Receiver Receipt`
       END `Last Receipt`
       FROM (SELECT max(`Transaction ID`) `Transaction ID`,
                    `Sender or Receiver`
                    FROM (SELECT max(`Transaction ID`) `Transaction ID`,
                                 `Sender` `Sender or Receiver`
                                 FROM `elbat`
                                 GROUP BY `Sender`
                          UNION ALL
                          SELECT max(`Transaction ID`) `Transaction ID`,
                                 `Receiver` `Sender or Receiver`
                                 FROM `elbat`
                                 GROUP BY `Receiver`) `Last Transaction`
                    GROUP BY `Sender or Receiver`) `Last Transaction`
            INNER JOIN `elbat`
                       ON `elbat`.`Transaction ID` = `Last Transaction`.`Transaction ID`;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0bbdc0987a7def2be176055a915e49a5)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table of customers, you can do:

```
select c.*,
       (select max(t.transactionid)
        from t
        where c.customerId in (t.sender, t.receiver)
       ) as last_transactionid
from customers c;
```

That could have bad performance characteristics.  This version might be better with the right indexes:

```
select c.*,
       greatest( (select max(t.transactionid)
                  from t
                  where c.customerId = t.sender
                 ),
                 (select max(t.transactionid)
                  from t
                  where c.customerId = t.receiver
                 )
               ) as last_transactionid
from customers c;
```